# Convex set equals convex functions within optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can optimizing a convex function subject to convex constraints be written as optimizing the function subject to a convex set? Does the intersection of convex nonlinear ineualities necessarily describe a convex set? In notation,
is
minimize $f(x)$
subject to $g_i(x)\le0, \forall i$, where $f$ and $g_i$ are convex functions equivalent to minimizing $f$ over a convex set $\mathcal{C}$ corresponding to the constraints (if that is true)?

Comment: Do you mean "subject to $g_i(x)\geq 0$"?

Comment: @smcc yes, fixed

Comment: Or did you mean $g_i(x)\leq 0$? (It matters here.)

Comment: "the intersection of convex functions" This phrase commits a category error. It makes no sense to say "the intersection of convex functions". You can intersect sets, not functions. What you *can* say is "the intersections of convex nonlinear inequalities", because generally it is understood that each inequality describes a set.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that a convex function is also quasiconvex and therefore has lower level sets that are convex sets. Thus if $g_i$ is convex then the set of $x$ such that $g_i(x)\leq 0$ is a convex set. The set $\mathcal{C}$ is the intersection of these sets over $i$. Since the intersection of convex sets is convex, $\mathcal{C}$ is convex.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization#Convex_optimization_problem